# Why are multiple classes being added?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to add a class that has a border-left that is either green, orange or red depending on some json. The 3 classes are called easy, medium, hard.

```
$.getJSON("http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts", function(data){
    var fetch_info = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        $('.result').append("<section>" +  value.title.rendered + value.content.rendered + "</section>");
        if (value.acf.sick === "Easy") {
            $('section').addClass('easy');
        } 
        if (value.acf.sick === "Medium") {
            $('section').addClass('medium');
        } 
        if (value.acf.sick === "Hard") {
            $('section').addClass('hard');
        }
    }); 
});
```

This is the json I recieve:

acf     {1}
 sick   :   Hard

Sick can be either Easy, Medium and Hard, so I thought:

```
if (value.acf.sick === "Easy") {
            $('section').addClass('easy');
        }
```

Would only add the class easy, to the sections with the value.acf.sick === "Easy" but for some reason my HTML looks like this...

```
<section class="hard easy medium">...</section>
<section class="easy hard medium">...</section>
<section class="hard easy medium">...</section>
<section class="easy medium">...</section>
<section class="medium">...</section>
<section class="medium">...</section>
```

All the first classes are correct, but for some reason it's adding multiple classes, and I can't seem to figure out why?

Comment: addClass doesnt remove previous added class to the selector element. So the class just gets added up more. 
For eg: first came hard then easy then medium.
So you will either have to use jquery attr to set class or you can do it like this
`$('section').removeClass().addClass('easy');`

Comment: Hmm.. That seems to leave every section with only the medium class..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here in this peace of code is select all `section elements`, and append the current `class`. While you just want to manipulate the current `jQuery object`.

```
$('section').addClass('hard');
```

In the first loop this will select the one and only `section tag`. In the second loop it will select both `section tags`. In the third...

Try to think in `jQuery objects`. First create a `jQuery object` and append it to an existing `HTML` element. Then insert the `class`. It's your choice to `append` it directly or later on.

```
$.getJSON('http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', function(data){
  var fetch_info = '';

  $.each(data, function(key, value){
      // create a jQuery object and append it to a HTML element
      var section = $('<section>', {
                      text: value.title.rendered + value.content.rendered
                    }).appendTo('.result');

      // Add a class based on the JSON value
      if (value.acf.sick === 'Easy') {
          section.addClass('easy');
      } 
      else if (value.acf.sick === 'Medium') {
          section.addClass('medium');
      } 
      else if (value.acf.sick === 'Hard') {
          section.addClass('hard');
      }

      // or append it later
      // $('.result').append(section);
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Good for you! Here is some reading about adding elements in different ways. http://marcgrabanski.com/building-html-in-jquery-and-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Because you add the classnames not to a specific element but to all section elements on each "each" iteration. Inside the loop use $(this).addClass(...) instead of $('section').addClass ...

Answer (score 1):

`$('section')` selects every element that is currently in the DOM, so the element you currently added and all elements added before.

To solve that problem you could first save the newly created section into a variable, and add the calss to that element

```js
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  var section = $("<section>" + value.title.rendered + value.content.rendered + "</section>");
  $('.result').append(section);

  if (value.acf.sick === "Easy") {
    section.addClass('easy');
  }
  if (value.acf.sick === "Medium") {
    section.addClass('medium');
  }
  if (value.acf.sick === "Hard") {
    section.addClass('hard');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to identify the sections individually:

```
$.getJSON("http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts", function(data){
    var fetch_info = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        $('.result').append("<section id=\"section"+key+"\">" +  value.title.rendered + value.content.rendered + "</section>");
        var id = '#section'+key;
        if (value.acf.sick === "Easy") {
            $(id).addClass('easy');
        } 
        if (value.acf.sick === "Medium") {
            $(id).addClass('medium');
        } 
        if (value.acf.sick === "Hard") {
            $(id).addClass('hard');
        }
    }); 
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

A more javascript clean way of doing this using DOM.

```
$.getJSON("http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts", function(data) {
    var fetch_info = '';
    var result = document.querySelector('.result');
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var section = document.createElement('section');
        section.innerHTML = data[i].title.rendered + data[i].content.rendered;
        section.className = data[i].acf.sick.toLowerCase(); // If data[i].acf.sick is always going to be from easy medium or hard
        result.appendChild(section);
    }
});
```

Comment: I voted it down. Nothing is wrong with it. But to come up with vanilla javascript when somebody asks a jquery question is just useless.